# Arduino - Counter:50: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, arduino

This is my code it is for my Sainsmart Arduino Uno.:

```
void buttonChange() {
  if (digitalRead(button) == LOW) {
    ltp2 = ltp;
    ltp = millis();
    if (number == 0 || ltp -= ltp2 > 500){ 
      number += 1;
      displayNumber();
    }
  }
}
```

I receive this error:

```
counter.ino: In function 'void buttonChange()':
counter:50: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `digitalRead`?

Comment: @haccks It's a function.

Comment: You need to provide the code that declares `ltp2`, `ltp`, and `number`.  You probably need to include all of `counter.ino` so we can see which line is line 50.`

Comment: Thanks. I found the error. I need to change the -= to just - as I don't want to change the int.

Comment: Haacks, digitalRead is an arduino function testing for an input to a pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to change what ltp is. Just use the minus.

```
if (number == 0 || ltp -= ltp2 > 500){
```

Change it to:

```
if (number == 0 || ltp - ltp2 > 500){
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some parentheses here:

```
if (number == 0 || ltp -= ltp2 > 500){
```

Change it to:

```
if (number == 0 || (ltp -= ltp2) > 500){
```